# Are the searches in SharePoint recorded anywhere? Is this possible?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, sharepoint-search

I am wondering if all searches done in my company's SharePoint is recorded somewhere in a database.

The SharePoint intranet is difficult to navigate and hard to find files / news that we need. One idea I have is to read the existing searches that fellow team members are doing, and use that knowledge to better 'tag' documents so that they can be found easily.

Is something like this a possibility in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePointOnline:
Go to the More features page of the new SharePoint admin center, and sign in with an account that has admin permissions for your organization. Under Search, select Open then Select View Usage Reports.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint on-prem there are canned Search Reports in the Site Collection and in the Search Service Application. They show a summary of queries for many various categories. They aren't great, but aside from using IIS Logs, they are the best you've got.

**Number of Queries**
This report shows the number of search queries performed. Use this report to identify search query volume trends and to determine times of high and low search activity.

**Top Queries by Day, Top Queries by Month**
This report shows the most popular search queries. Use this report to understand what types of information visitors are seeking.

**Abandoned Queries by Day, Abandoned Queries by Month**
This report shows popular search queries that received low click-through. Use this report to identify search queries that might create user dissatisfaction and to improve the discoverability of content. Then, consider using query rules to improve the query's results.

**No Result Queries by Day, No Result Queries by Month** 
This report shows popular search queries that returned no results. Use this report to identify search queries that might create user dissatisfaction and to improve the discoverability of content. Then, consider using query rules to improve the query's results.

**Query Rule Usage by Day, Query Rule Usage by Month**

This report shows how often query rules trigger, how many dictionary terms they use, and how often users click their promoted results. Use this report to see how useful your query rules and promoted results are to users.

[View search usage reports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/view-search-usage-reports)